# How to use Python to log into Facebook/Myspace and crawl the content?

Tags: python, authentication, session, post, web-crawler

Right now, I can crawl regular pages using urllib2.

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://stackoverflow.com')
request.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
htmlSource = response.read()
print htmlSource
```

However...I would like to simulate a POST (or fake sessions)? so that I can go into Facebook and crawl. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to keep the cookie your site of choice sends you when you log in; that's what keeps your session. With `urllib2`, you do this by creating an Opener object that supports cookie processing:

```
import urllib2, cookielib
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
```

With this opener, you can do requests, either GET or POST:

```
content = opener.open(urllib2.Request(
    "http://social.netwo.rk/login",
    "user=foo&pass=bar")
).read()
```

As there's a second parameter to urllib2.Request, it'll be a POST request -- if that's None, you end up with a GET request. You can also add HTTP headers, either with `.add_header` or by handing the constructor a dictionary (or a tuple-tuple) of headers. Read the manual for urllib2.Request for more information.

That should get you started! Good luck.

(ps: If you don't need read access to the cookies, you can just omit creating the cookie jar yourself; the HTTPCookieProcessor will do it for you.)

Answer (score 4):

The [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library is an easy way to emulate a browser in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can do POST requests by first encoding the data using urllib, and then sending the request using urllib2 just as you are doing now.

This is explained in [this article](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

OR you may use PyCurl as a choice...